# What is a component, template and page in AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

Please give me an overview of what a component, page, page component and template is in AEM. How are they related to each other. Please give example if possible.

Suggest any site to start as a beginner.

Comment: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics.html

Answer (score 5):

Your are mixing up technical and non-technical terms a bit. So I try to explain it in two ways: From an abstract, non-technical level, and from a technical point of view.

**Abstract, non-technical explanation**

The content of your AEM project mostly contains *pages*. A *page* is tied to an URL like `www.example.com/products/teddybear`. When a user opens this *page* he sees the content of the *page*. An image of the teddy bear, some descriptive text but also the header and footer of your *page*. This is where components come in. Content like the image, the text, the header and footer are all different *components* on that *page*.

> *Pages* are composed of *components*.

**Technical explanation**

When developers try to implement *pages* and *components* they will need to create *page templates*, *page components* and *components*.

*Page templates* are basically XML files that define a few things about the page. For example the title of the page (e.g. "Content Page", "News Page", etc.) that is shown in the page creation dialog, a description, allowed parent pages (templates), allowed child pages (templates) and paths in your content where this page template can be used. Besides those things you can also define the basic structure of the page. Add a parsys, already add components to this parsys so those components are "hard wired" into every page you create.

*Page components* are the "implementation" of *page templates*. Here you can add the HTML for that page.

*Components* are the building blocks of pages. A component usually contains a JSP or HTML file that contains the HTML markup and maybe some business logic for that component.

Obviously, there are a lot more things to consider. But this should give you a basic overview over the relationship between all of those things.

Links:

- [Page Template documentation AEM 6.2](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/templates/page-templates-static.html)
- [Component documentation AEM 6.2](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/components.html)